# Silverstripe 3 wrong sort with special chars (umlauts)

Tags: php, silverstripe

Silverstripe 3.6
When trying to sort an ArrayList by a field that starts with special chars - german umlauts in my case - the result is no "natural sort"

Example:

```
$arrayList  = ArrayList::create(array(
  ArrayData::create(array('Title' => 'Ccc')),
  ArrayData::create(array('Title' => 'Zzz')),
  ArrayData::create(array('Title' => 'Ööö')),
  ArrayData::create(array('Title' => 'Aaa')),
  ArrayData::create(array('Title' => 'Rrr')),
  ArrayData::create(array('Title' => 'Ooo')),
  ArrayData::create(array('Title' => 'Äää'))
));

Debug::dump($arrayList->column('Title'));
$sortedList = $arrayList->sort('Title');
Debug::dump($sortedList->column('Title'));
```

Result of the orginal list:

```
[0] => Ccc
[1] => Zzz
[2] => Ööö
[3] => Aaa
[4] => Rrr
[5] => Ooo
[6] => Äää
```

Result of the sorted List:

```
[0] => Aaa
[1] => Ccc
[2] => Ooo
[3] => Rrr
[4] => Zzz
[5] => Äää
[6] => Ööö
```

The expectation would be:

```
[0] => Aaa
[1] => Äää
[2] => Ccc
[3] => Ooo
[4] => Ööö
[5] => Rrr
[6] => Zzz
```

Using php5.6 with intl extension.
Any ideas, how to get this working ?

Comment: What is the locale context you're running this in?

Comment: I have a feeling that this should be raised as a framework issue: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues/new

Comment: Current locale is de_DE, but it should not matter (IMHO)

Comment: Hmmm.. https://www.duolingo.com/comment/24588718/Placement-of-%C3%BC-%C3%A4-%C3%B6-and-%C3%9F-in-the-German-alphabet according to this youd like it to be in dictionary / phonebook order ? so basically that should be valid what you are getting in some extent.. So if you want to go against that maybe use our own sorting logic for the arrays or change the locale settings so it would affect that, not sure is there something that can be quickly set

Comment: as a test https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.6/model/ArrayList.php#L451  if you change it to SORT_NATURAL  does that fix the issue? Did not actually check what of the http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php values would get php to sort presumably german correctly